# Can you use count() for an entire list instead of one variable?

Tags: python-3.x

Is there a way to use count() for an entire list rather than have to use it on each variable seperately? If this is possible it would save me alot of typing.

```
var1 = random.randint(u,v)
var2 = random.randint(w,x)
var3 = random.randint(y,z)

listName = [var1,var2,var3]

listName.count(x)
listName.count(y) #can you get the count for an entire list instead of having to do them
listName.count(z) #all seperately? It would be much more efficient.
```

Comment: What's `daysPerWk`? Show its definition!

Comment: `randint` takes two parameters, not one. `list` is a type, so I don't think you want to re-assign that, and `.count` isn't a method for `daysPerWk`, which isn't even defined.

Comment: @nbro it is changed. It was supposed to be renamed to listName

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of creating a list with random contents and then showing the length and sum.

```
import random

my_list = [
  random.randint(1, 10),
  random.randint(1, 10),
  random.randint(1, 10)
]

print("The value of my_list is {0}".format(my_list))

print("The length of my_list is {0}".format(len(my_list)))

print("The sum of my_list is {0}".format(sum(my_list)))
```

Sample Output:

```
The value of my_list is [4, 8, 4]
The length of my_list is 3
The sum of my_list is 16
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

`list.count(item)` returns the number of times `item` appears in a list.

If you want to know how many times each item appears in the list, **if it appears in the list**, you can do this:

```
original_list = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4]
uniques = list(set(original_list))

counts = {}
for unique in uniques:
    counts[unique] = original_list.count(unique)

print(counts)
```

which should print something like

```
{
    1: 2,
    2: 1,
    3: 1,
    4: 3
}
```

Here's more info on the `set` data type:

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets

While we're at it, you can also use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter([1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4])
print(dict(counts))
```

and this should print the same dictionary as above.